# jQuery multiple elements .click(function()

Tags: jquery, function, click, element

I'm trying to give the same function to 2 elements.

Here's what I've got which isn't working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#menu a, p.bodytext a').click(function() {
      $('#content_bg').load($(this).attr('href')+' #content');
      return false;
   });
 });
```

Now it works if I go like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#menu a').click(function() {
      $('#content_bg').load($(this).attr('href')+' #content');
      return false;
   });
 });
```

or like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('p.bodytext a').click(function() {
      $('#content_bg').load($(this).attr('href')+' #content');
      return false;
   });
 });
```

But does not work with them together.

Suggestions?

Comment: That seems unlikely; are you sure the selectors are correct? That you've not missed out a comma, or misspelled something?

Comment: Works fine for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/C2e9r/

Comment: What is not working? Can you describe the error?

Comment: In the code I'm using now, the #menu a is working, but the p.bodytext a is not. When a link is clicked from the bodytext paragraph, it refreshes the page and loads the content, whereas the #menu a link opens the link within the frame it's supposed to go on the page, without refreshing the page.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem with [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), perhaps, so you can let us see what you're working with?

Comment: The url is: http://tinyurl.com/7dmlctq  (If referring to it, please keep the url masked to prevent search engines from indexing it)
Also, if it makes any difference, it is in the Typo3 CMS system.
Take a look at the url after each click. The url should never change, as the page is supposed to stay the same with the content changing dynamically with the jQuery.

Comment: So your click event handler is actually executed in both cases, but it just isn't doing what you want in one case?  You should probably edit that into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [add method](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to add elements to a set:

```
$('#menu a').add('p.bodytext a').on();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
   $('#menu, p.bodytext').find('a').on('click', function() {
      $('#content').load($(this).attr('href')+' #content');
      return false;
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class name instead of id.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.myClass').click(function() {
      $('#content').load($(this).attr('href')+' #content');
      return false;
   });
 });
```

Comment: #menu a works, it's the p.bodytext a that doesn't with the code I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add a receive the parameter 'e' and do a e.preventDefault().

like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu a, p.bodytext a').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#content').load($(this).attr('href')+' #content');
     return false;
  });
});
```